# NAT device on L3 Switch

Tags: cisco, routing, nat, networking

This is our current network topology. Everything works fine, but I have some concerns about it.

I'm questioning myself about the following, and would like to improve what we current have.

The two (actually 3) L2 switch are stacked together with some bladestack modules.

- Why is the Edgemax-pro (our NAT device) not directly connected on the L3 switch ? (that would be a router on a stick ?) As far as I understand, the L3 is already a router on a stick.
- Do I need to use the L3 Cisco as a Gateway for our clients (we're doing some interVLAN)
- The L3 Cisco should use the Edgemax-pro as a GW ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A layer-3 switch *is* a router, too, so it doesn't use a default gateway; it routes to other routers. It is handling the routing for your LAN, but it will have a default route pointing to your WAN router.

Without including your network device configurations, it is not possible to be exact, but you probably have a VLAN from the LAN router (layer-3 switch) to the WAN router that is essentially a routed link. That would be the equivalent of a direct connection between the two devices.

The network hosts would use the layer-3 switch SVIs as their gateways, and the layer-3 switch and WAN router would be configured to route between them, either with statically configured routes, or by sharing a routing protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't sure if it was good practice to connect the WAN router on our L2 switch, and having a route on the L3 switch pointing to it. Appreciate !